# linq to sql. two relative tables

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have two tables:

```
tab1                                                     tab2

ID | Name | Sername | PostID                  ID | PostDecription
```

The question: how can I show in tab1 in cell PostID cell from tab2 PostDecription if PostDecription could has value NULL?

```
(from p in tab1 join s in tab2 on p.PostID equals
                                         s.ID select new
                    {                 
                       ID = p.ID,
                       Name= p.Name,
                       Sername = p.Sername,
                       PostID = s.PostDecription,

                    })
```

Using this code I can get only cells that have the same value in two tables. What about case when PostDecription could has value "NULL"???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a left join

```
from p in tab1 
join s in tab2 on p.PostID equals s.ID into tab2s 
from s in tab2s.DefaultIfEmpty()    
select new
                    {                 
                       ID = p.ID,
                       Name= p.Name,
                       Sername = p.Sername,
                       PostID = s.PostDecription,

                    }
```